# Continuously updating text Android

Tags: java, android

The following are my textfields, radio buttons etc.:

```
et1             =    Edit Text Field
radioButton1    =    Radio Button (part of group1)
radioButton2    =    Radio Button (part of group1)
textView2       =    Text View
```

What I am trying to is to constantly have textView2 update depending on what is inside et1 and which Radio Button is selected.

I was thinking the problem could be to do that the method convertUp / convertDown. It only runs when a Radio Button is actually clicked, and not selected.

If this is the problem can someone tell me how to do this. And if it is not, can someone explain to me where I am going wrong. I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code I use:

("mark" is the variable that will be updating in textView2 and "value" is the variable that "mark" depends on - as seen in the methods)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    double mark = 0;
    double value = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

        try{
            value = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            value = 1.0;
        }

        OnClickListener listener1 = new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                mark = convertUp(value);    
            }        
        };

        OnClickListener listener2 = new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                mark = convertDown(value);    
            }     
        };

        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        rb1.setOnClickListener(listener1);

        RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        rb2.setOnClickListener(listener2);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        tv1.setText(""+mark);    

    }
```

Comment: You should move  `value = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());` in side `onClick()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do several things to have it constantly updating.

First, you need a `TextWatcher` for the `EditText` which would modify the `textView` every time you input a new letter.

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
      try{
         value = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
      } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
         value = 1.0;
      }

      if(rb1.isChecked()){ mark = convertUp(value);  }
      else{ mark = convertDown(value); }

      tv1.setText(""+mark); //will update ur tV every time you input a lleter
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
});
```

You also need to do this to modify your `textView` in case you change the `radioButton`

```
OnClickListener listener1 = new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
              value = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
            } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
              value = 1.0;
            }

            mark = convertUp(value);  

            tv1.setText(""+mark);  
        }        
    };

    OnClickListener listener2 = new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
              value = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
            } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
              value = 1.0;
            }

            mark = convertDown(value);   

            tv1.setText(""+mark); 
        }     
    };
```

Hope it helps! Good Luck!

Comment: is beforeTextChanged() or afterTextChanged() needed ?

Comment: not at all but I think the method `addTextChangedListener` requires it! Try deleting them to see if you get any error.

Comment: Oh of course, doesn't Override imply they are required, but needn't be used. It does not allow the methods to be deleted

Comment: I have a problem trying to "access local variable within inner class". Where should I declare the objects text, tv1, etc. I have tried inside onCreate method which doesn't allow the variables to be globally accessed. And declaring the variables at the same location as mark, value yields a NullPointerException runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Or try tv1.setText(""+mark);    in OnClickListener listener1 and OnClickListener listener2